# How to remove PostgreSQL 9.6 from macOS Big Sur(intel) - Uninstaller fails with "Bad CPU type in executable"

Tags: postgresql, macos

I wonder if anyone can help....I upgraded to macOS BigSur(Intel). I am trying to remove PostgreSQL 9.6 via uninstaller script and receive the following error:

```
$ cd /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS/
$ sudo ./installbuilder.sh

./installbuilder.sh: line 20: ./osx-intel: Bad CPU type in executable
```

I think it is EnterpriseDB version of postgreSQL....

How do I manually remove PostgreSQL EnterpriseDB?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

1. Download latest PostgreSql 9.6 patch at https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
2. Reinstall PostgreSql 9.6 downloaded
3. open /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/uninstall-postgresql.app/